# Can I use "_id" field in $graphlookup operation in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible to use "id" (string) property to match on in the graphlookup ? using any other string property it seems to work.

e.g. below query returns empty "groups" (where members.userId == id)

```
Collection1:
{ 
    "_id" : "U2", 
    "displayName" : "testName"
}

Collection2:
{ 
    "_id" : "UG1", 
    "members" : [
        {
            "userId" : "U2", 
             "admin" : false
        }
    ], 
    "name" : "testGroup"
}

db.collection1.aggregate( [
    {
      "$match": {
        "_id": "U2"
      }
    },
    {
      "$graphLookup": {
        "from": "collection2",
        "startWith": "$id",
        "connectFromField": "_id",
        "connectToField": "members.userId",
        "as": "groups"
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

however below query would return matching "groups" (where members.userId == displayName)

```
db.collection1.aggregate( [
    {
      "$match": {
        "_id": "U2"
      }
    },
    {
      "$graphLookup": {
        "from": "collection2",
        "startWith": "$displayName",
        "connectFromField": "displayName",
        "connectToField": "members.userId",
        "as": "groups"
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

**UPDATE**:

below query works fine (had to add **$** in the startwith clause):

```
db.collection1.aggregate( [
    {
      "$match": {
        "_id": "U2"
      }
    },
    {
        $graphLookup: {
            from: "collection2",
            startWith: "$_id", 
            connectFromField: "_id",
            connectToField: "members.userId",
            as: "groups"
         }
    }
  ]
);
```

Comment: It is currently not possible. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22781

Comment: That issue talks about if you store the _id as Object Id and then want to use for the match; my question is when _id is a custom generated String already. Am I missing something or these two are different problems?

Comment: Can you add sample document from both collection ?

Comment: Added the sample documents in the question.

Comment: Added the updated query that worked. Thanks @Veeram